# Meteor get client IP address behind Nginx Passenger

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger

I'm running Meteor behind Nginx with Passenger.

this.connection.clientAddress returns the IP in my dev environment but behind nginx and passenger, it's undefined.

X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; added to the nginx config does not change anything.

Here what I added to my nginx conf:

```
passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT 1;
passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR $remote_addr;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On proxy machine set:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

On proxied machine add (**Replace *10.0.1.1* with your *proxy machine* local network IP**):

```
set_real_ip_from  10.0.1.1;
```